# Alternative to Where Exist clause MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, exists

I have this select statement that is taking quite a while to run on a larger dataset

```
select lookup_svcscat_svcscatnew.SVCSCAT_NEW_DESC as svc_type, 
        enrolid, msclmid, dx1, dx2, dx3, 
        proc1,msk_cpt_mapping.surg_length_cd as SL_CD,
        msk_cpt_mapping.days as day_window,o.svcdate_form, pay,
        table_label
from ccaeo190_ky o
    left join lookup_svcscat_svcscatnew on o.svcscat = lookup_svcscat_svcscatnew.svcscat
    left join msk_cpt_mapping on o.proc1 = msk_cpt_mapping.cpt_code
where EXISTS 
        (
        select 1 
        from eoc_op_mapping e
        where e.msclmid = o.msclmid
            and e.enrolid = o.enrolid
            and proc1 =27447
        )
ORDER BY svcdate_form, msclmid;
```

I want to return any row in my ccaeo190_ky table that meets the requirements of the where EXISTS clause on table eoc_op_mapping. Is there any way to achieve these results using joins or select statements?

I was thinking something like:

```
select lookup_svcscat_svcscatnew.SVCSCAT_NEW_DESC as svc_type, 
        o.enrolid, o.msclmid, dx1, dx2, dx3, 
        proc1,msk_cpt_mapping.surg_length_cd as SL_CD,
        msk_cpt_mapping.days as day_window,o.svcdate_form, pay,
        table_label
from ccaeo190_ky o
    left join lookup_svcscat_svcscatnew on o.svcscat = lookup_svcscat_svcscatnew.svcscat
    left join msk_cpt_mapping on o.proc1 = msk_cpt_mapping.cpt_code
    inner join
        (select msclmid, SUM(IF(proc1 = 27447,1,0)) AS cpt 
        from eoc_op_mapping 
        group by enrolid
        HAVING cpt > 0) e 
on e.enrolid = o.enrolid
group by o.enrolid;
```

But I don't know if this is in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually `EXISTS` performs better than a join.

If you want to try a join, this the equivalent to your `WHERE EXISTS`:

```
.......................................................
inner join (
  select distinct msclmid, enrolid
  from eoc_op_mapping
  where proc1 = 27447
) e on e.msclmid = o.msclmid and e.enrolid = o.enrolid
.......................................................
```

You can remove `distinct` if there are no duplicate `msclmid, enrolid` combinations in `eoc_op_mapping`.

Comment: awesome thank you so much! For some reason the inner join returned my results in seconds, while the WHERE Exists has been running for about 24hrs.